# Passport oauth token path not found in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

In laravel5.4  passport authentication is not working. there are error about in in oauth /token file may not found where is this file path #oauth #laravel #token #passport #authentication

Comment: Where does generate oauth /token file??